# Prove that $-(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)> abc$ if one of $(a+b-c),(a-b+c),(-a+b+c)$ is negative.

Tags: inequality

I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023485/the-inequality-abc-geqa-bcab-cbc-a-holds-for-a-b-c-geq-0) and [many others](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170813/prove-abca-bcab-c-leq-abc-where-a-b-and-c-are-positive-real) with the same inequality, and I wondered if in the case of a negative RHS, if the absolute would be bigger than $abc$. After a couple of examples I couldn't find any contradictions. Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: I'm curious what type of examples you considered.  (Short answer is it's false, by considering $c = a + b + \varepsilon$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh, yeah! My bad, I copy pasted it wrong!

Comment: The edit doesn't change my comment's point.  For $\varepsilon =0$ you would have $0$ is greater than a positive number, which is absurd, so by continuity it remains absurd at least for small $\varepsilon$.  I am still curious what type of examples you considered.

Comment: @BrianMoehring if $c=a+b$ then none of $(a+b-c),(a-b+c),(-a+b+c)$ is negative, so it's not taken into account

Comment: @BrianMoehring I just wrote a short python program that tries different combinations

Answer (score 0):

The task's statement is wrong.

Here is a family of counterexamples:

Let $a=b= xc$ then we have to show $-(2x-1) c^3 \ge x^2 c^3$. If $c >0$ this becomes

$1-2x - x^2\ge 0 $. Let $0 < x <0.5$ and  $c >0$ then only the first term is negative, as required. However, then  $f(x) = 1-2x - x^2\ge 0 $ does not hold, since $f(x) \ge 0 $ holds only for $0 < x < \sqrt{2} -1 \simeq 0.414$ whereas for all $0.414 \simeq \sqrt{2} -1 < x < 0.5$ we have that $f(x) \le 0 $. This contradicts your claim. $\qquad \Box$